# Azure .NET 5 isolated functions and how to update a table storage using function binding

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, .net-5

I'm trying to update a table storage row in an [Azure .NET 5 isolated functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide), where I used [function binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#bindings) (the environment is **Function v. 3**).

I reproduced [this example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/blob/main/samples/Extensions/Table/TableFunction.cs) (see the code below), but **I can't find a way to update "MyTableData" with an existing partition key**. If I try to use the same partition key, the function binding doesn't execute an "upsert" and I always get an "Internal Server Error".

Do you know if there's a way to manage the update and insert with function binding?

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace SampleApp
{
    public static class TableFunction
    {
        [Function("TableFunction")]
        [TableOutput("OutputTable", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]
        public static MyTableData Run([QueueTrigger("table-items")] string input,
            [TableInput("MyTable", "MyPartition", "{queueTrigger}")] MyTableData tableInput,
            FunctionContext context)
        {
            var logger = context.GetLogger("TableFunction");

            logger.LogInformation($"PK={tableInput.PartitionKey}, RK={tableInput.RowKey}, Text={tableInput.Text}");

            return new MyTableData()
            {
                PartitionKey = "queue",
                RowKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                Text = $"Output record with rowkey {input} created at {DateTime.Now}"
            };
        }
    }

    public class MyTableData
    {
        public string PartitionKey { get; set; }

        public string RowKey { get; set; }

        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that there's a [bug with the function bindings](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/459)

Comment: How did you get TableOutput attritbute to compile? Mine doesn't want to compile it. Using .NET 6 and adding all the standard .NET NuGet packages for a new Azure Function

Comment: @OliverNilsen I remember that in the end I decided to don't use the ["function bindings"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#bindings), and there is an issue still opened about writing a single row (see the link in the first comment). But, if you look to the MS reference guide, you can find an [example to write a single table row](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table-output?tabs=in-process%2Cstorage-extension&pivots=programming-language-csharp#example) trough the function bindings.

Comment: @OliverNilsen of course, pay attention because in the [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table-output?tabs=in-process%2Cstorage-extension&pivots=programming-language-csharp#example), **the implementation change between "In-process" and "Isolated" process function** (you can switch the example using the labels on top). The usage of "Table Output" is different between the two modes.